# Reactstrap Row and Col are not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, layout, reactstrap

I use reactstrap and i want to display 2 elements in a row, but i get a column: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Awb.png)

This is my code:

```
export default class Intro extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>HOO</Col>
                    <Col>BAA</Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

```
function App() {
    return (
            <Intro />
    );
}
```

I'm new in React. Where could I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not importing Bootstrap CSS in the `index.js` file, you should add:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

at the top of `index.js` or `App.js` file